# Ajax script is repeating istself

Tags: php, ajax, repeat

Probably I'm just stupid, but I can't explain why this java/ajax script is repeating itself a random times (2 to 20 times...):

```
function getScreenSize(w, h) {
    if (w != $(window).width() || h != $(window).height()) {
        w = $(window).width();
        h = $(window).height();
        $.ajax({
            url:"modules/set_screen_size.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                w:w,
                h:h,
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                if (data == "changed") {
                    location.reload();
                }
            },
        });
    }
}
```

set_screen_size.php puts screen sizes in php-session-variables, therefore a page reload is necessary to make them available in the original page.

I have verified that getScreenSize() is called only once from the html(php)-page but the ajax-call is repeated a random times.

To "solve" the problem in a kind and to avoid reloads after every repeat I return an 400 Bad Request from set_screen_size.php when called from ajay with the same values and only return the word "changed" when the values passed from ajax have changed...

What I cannot explain is why getScreenSize() calls set_screen_size.php several times.

Can you give me a hint about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Surely this line `location.reload();` causes the page to be reloaded. What is it that causes `getScreenSize()` to run?

Comment: of course location.reload reloads the page, this is not the problem. The problem is that the ajax-call to set_screen_size.php is repeated. With my described "solution" I can avoid that several reloads occur, but this ajax calls the php script several times. getScreenSize() is called from the html-head of the page when loading. It is called only once.

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase. What causes the function `getScreenSize()` to be run?

Comment: PS: If you use AJAX to do things without reloading the page, it does seem a little odd that the first thing you do when a AJAX call reports a success _is reload the page_ ? Or is it just me that finds that rather odd??

Comment: Maybe it's odd, but I haven't found a better solution... I need to know screen size and orientation to serve the appropriate image sizes and portrait/landscape variants. In the head of the page I call getScreenSize(), passing the width/height values I have saved in S_SESSION. The ajax script should only execute when the current values are different. Then it calls set_screen_size.php which puts the new values in S_SESSION. Then a reload is necessary to make those session variable available.

Comment: @MarsFotografo Can't you have responsive images/page design? What if you set this size and then user resizes browser?

Comment: By now there are HTML/CSS tools/workflows available that let browsers decide which image size to show according to screen size. Might want to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: If you call `getScreenSize()` in the page <head> then when you reload the page the function gets which relaods the page so the function gets called again, and the page get reloaded and the function gets called again and ...ad infinitum

Comment: I distinct between portrait and landscape versions, each in 4 different sizes plus all of those as well as .jpg and .wepb which would make 16 entries in each srcset - with 40 images I think this would unnecessarily blow up the source code.
Furthermore I use a ken-burn-gallery script that needs an array with the image-files to show (not img tags). Yes, it doesn't help when the user changes screen size until s/he reloads the page or goes to another one.

Comment: the function getScreenSize() is called with the $_SESSION width and height values. Those values have been set with the last call of the script. After the reload the script is called again, but - if the values haven't changed/the screen wasn't resized - it should not execute because of the "if size-now != size-before" statement. Anyway: only ONE reload occurs due to my "solution", but still the ajax call is executed many times.